# Datepicker should not be affected by theme in android

Tags: android, datepicker, android-theme

I am having to set theme in android mainifest file
    `<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
        <item name="contentInsetStart">0dp</item>
        <item name="contentInsetEnd">0dp</item>
    </style>`

But due to this my datepicker's appearance changes.The android lollipop datepicker has changed to a simple datepicker like the one we get in android 4.0. I want that the datepicker's property should be OS specific and not be affected by the theme I set.How can I acheive this?

Answer (score 2):

You can do this way:

Just add below line:

```
android:datePickerMode="spinner"
```

**Datepicker.xml:**

```
<DatePicker
    android:id="@+id/startDatePicker"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:datePickerMode="spinner"
    android:calendarViewShown="false" >
</DatePicker>
```

You will get same dialog in lollipop also.

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.I will try and let you know

Comment: @Georgemicrolucid, Okay, np

Comment: I have set this in my style <style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
        <item name="contentInsetStart">0dp</item>
        <item name="contentInsetEnd">0dp</item>
        <item name="android:datePickerMode">spinner</item>
  </style>
but it is not working.We are using datepicker like this without xml,    datePicker=new DatePickerDialog (this,HandleDateSet, dtStartDate.Date.Year, dtStartDate.Date.Month - 1, dtStartDate.Date.Day);

Comment: @Georgemicrolucid, can you please try datePicker.setSpinnersShown(true);